# Loading numpy files into memory to append arrays causing MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy

When trying to run this:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

npfiles = glob.glob("*.npy")
npfiles.sort()

for file in npfiles:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        array = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
    try:
        test
    except NameError:
        test = array
    else:
        test = np.append(test, array)
array.shape
```

This is the error I receive:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.28 GiB for an array with shape (24115,) and data type <U14262
```

I'm trying to simply load several `.npy` files into memory and append them to one another. Their total size is only 1.58GB and I have 64GB of physical RAM.

I found that stackoverflow posts with the same problem were due to under-allocated virtual memory, and to overcome this users increased alloted virtual memory by increasing the page size maximum. Since I am using Windows 10, I increased virtual memory by doing [this.](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10,36929.html)

I've rebooted my PC and still experience the issue. I am baffled.

Comment: Could you print `test` size at each iteration?

Comment: are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Python?

Comment: Also can you check if you have the 64bit Python and not 32bit? Another small optimization may be to check datatypes and decide if you can downcast data without losing useful information (https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: When you use `np.append` iteratively, you need space for at least 2 full copies.  `np.concatenate` makes a new array, copying values from all the arguments.  List append with one final `np.array(...)` is more efficient, though probably won't help with overall memory use in your case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought for certain I had the 64 bit version installed, but it was the 32 bit version. I reinstalled the 64 bit version and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the 64 bit version of python because I have a 64 bit operating system and machine. This fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

My experience of this error has always been when I've been cavalier with the data I'm using, and reading in too much and trying to store it all at once. I'm not 100% sure from your question whether you are able to process the data per file as you load it in, or whether the files are independent.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

def process_my_data(data_array):
    . . . 
    # do data processing here
    return processed_data

def do_something_with_all_processed_data(my_processed_data):
    combined_arr = np.array([])
    for k in my_processed_data:
        combined_arr = np.append(processed_data[k], combined_arr)
    print(combined_arr.shape)
    
def load_and_process_files():
    npfiles = sorted(glob.glob("*.npy"))
    
    my_processed_data = dict()
    for file in npfiles:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            array = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
        my_processed_data[file] = process_my_data(array)
    do_something_with_all_processed_data(my_processed_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_and_process_files()
```

In cases of large data sets, it's always nice as well to save the output of any processes in to a file which you can read again later so you don't always have to crunch through gigabytes of data.